# Add class to index using jquery html

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<tr>
 <td class="a 1"></td>
 <td class="a 2"></td>
 <td class="a 3"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td class="b 4"></td>
 <td class="b 5"></td>
 <td class="b 6"></td>
</tr>

if(val){
  for(var i=0; i<val; i++){
    $('.'+i).addClass("somecl");    
  }    
}
```

How to add *class* looping through using index in jQuery?

Lets say, we have in val 3 it should add *somecl* class to class a 1, a 2 and a 3.
And if it is val = 4 it should add *somecl* to a 1, a 2, a 3 and b 4 as well. 
How can I do that? Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are nearly there.

Since there is no *class* named 0 exists, you can start the loop at `i=1` and end when `i<=val`. I think you do not need the *if* condition here.

```js
var val = 3;
for(var i=1; i<=val; i++){
  $('.'+i).addClass("somecl");    
}
```

```css
.somecl{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td class="a 1">11</td>
   <td class="a 2">22</td>
   <td class="a 3">33</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="b 4">44</td>
   <td class="b 5">55</td>
   <td class="b 6">66</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

***Few Alternative Solutions:***

You can use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate over all the *td* to check if the element has the class or not. If has then add the class.

***Please Note:*** *index* start from 0, that means 0 for first, 1 for second element and so on.

```js
var val = 3;
$('td').each(function(i){
  var i = i+1;
  if($(this).hasClass(i) && i <= val)
   $(this).addClass("somecl");    
});
```

```css
.somecl{color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td class="a 1">11</td>
   <td class="a 2">22</td>
   <td class="a 3">33</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="b 4">44</td>
   <td class="b 5">55</td>
   <td class="b 6">66</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can use [.eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified *index*.

```js
var val = 3;
for(var i=0; i<val; i++){
  $('td').eq(i).addClass("somecl");    
}
```

```css
.somecl{color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td class="a 1">11</td>
   <td class="a 2">22</td>
   <td class="a 3">33</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="b 4">44</td>
   <td class="b 5">55</td>
   <td class="b 6">66</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can also get all the elements in a variable, then use loop to set the *class* with the current *i* value as the *index* of the element in the variable.

```js
var el = $('td');
var val = 3;
for(var i=0; i<val; i++){
 $(el[i]).addClass("somecl");    
}
```

```css
.somecl{color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
   <td class="a 1">11</td>
   <td class="a 2">22</td>
   <td class="a 3">33</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td class="b 4">44</td>
   <td class="b 5">55</td>
   <td class="b 6">66</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The loop should ideally start from 1 to get the desired output.

```js
     const val=4;
    if(val){
      for(var i=1; i<=val; ++i){   
          $('.'+i).addClass("somecl");
      }    
    }
```

```css
.somecl{color: red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table>
      <tr>
       <td class="a 1">11</td>
       <td class="a 2">22</td>
       <td class="a 3">33</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
       <td class="b 4">44</td>
       <td class="b 5">55</td>
       <td class="b 6">66</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var val = prompt('Enter val : ') ;
  for(var i = 1; i <= val  ; i++ ) {
      $('.' + i).addClass('somecl') ;
  }
})
```

```css
.somecl {
  border: 1px solid orange ;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>

 <tr>
   <td class="a 1">a 1</td>
   <td class="a 2">a 2</td>
   <td class="a 3">a 3</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="b 4">b 4</td>
    <td class="b 5">b 5</td>
    <td class="b 6">b 6</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```